# What could be the cause of a limit in the voltage supplied to a capacitor?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

Recently I built a very basic 2-stage coil gun for a school project. Each coil was powered by an electrolytic capacitor. In order to charge the capacitor, the coil connected to an IGBT ([insulated-gate bipolar transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulated-gate_bipolar_transistor)). I controlled that would block the current during charging. When I wished to shoot the coil I would use an [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) to open the IGBT and then discharge the capacitor through the coil. There was also a diode to help protect the IGBT but I don't believe this was the source of the problem I faced. I also later learned that my diode didn't properly protect my IGBT, I am aware of my mistake in that regard and am only including it incase this is somehow the source of my problem. My capacitor was rated for 80 volts and had 0.1 farads of capacitance. I charged it to 70 volts to be safe but after the first discharge I was unable to charge it past 36 volts. After a decent amount of analysis I could not find a reason why this happened so I tried charging and discharging more times to see if I could find a pattern but it would simply plateau at arbitrarily low voltages without any clear pattern. I also noticed that when taken off the charger it would very slowly but noticeably leak voltage. After speaking to my professor about it, he theorized that I damaged the capacitor due to the fast discharge but I was wondering if there is another possible reason I hit certain voltage plateaus or how to avoid this problem in the future if this is the reason. Below is a picture of my circuit of one coil(the two coils are isolated but follows the same set up).

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you conencted the capacitor with the right polarity?

Comment: Yes, the polarity was correct. My understanding is that if the polarity was flipped I would have blown up the capacitor. Also I don't see how that would cause the voltage to fluctuate between charges.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes and no in that the back emf due to the rapidly changing current in the coil is a good example of Faraday's law in action?

Comment: We need to know **how** you are charging the cap, and also how about removing the cap from your project and charging it as a standalone component?

Comment: During the first discharge it might be that something in the circuit was damaged because of ringing (oscillation).

Comment: @Carl Witthoft To charge the capacitor I used a power supply that had a fixed 100 Volt output. I used a rheostat to ensure the current did not get too high and damage the power supply. I also used a multimeter to measure the voltage across the cap to ensure we did not go past our 70 volts mark and properly measured other known voltages with it. This leads me to believe that the multimeter functioned well. I also tested the voltage of the power supply without the capacitor and it was outputting the proper voltage.

Comment: @Qmechanic I have now asked this in the https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ page as well

Comment: Crossposted to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/622748/52589

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is $\text{rapidly changing current} \Rightarrow \text {large emf in opposition to change}$.

So what you need is a reverse biased diode **across** the coil.

[How to make an Electromagnetic Coil Gun](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/diy-simple-coil-gun) explains what to do with the circuit as below

[image]

In the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOQdg-07vtA) at about 0:30 the statement "here with a diode to release the reverse current" is made.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this leads to failure to reach expected voltage when charging?